# amCharts not validating data

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, amcharts

I have got a couple of pie and serial charts in my website and two charts do not render normally when there's no data. One chart(pie) displays nothing and the other chart(serial) throws an error `amcharts.js:113 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`.

I'm getting the data via Ajax and I have checked the console for the response data.

Here's my pie chart code:

```
jQuery.post('http://....', data, function(response) {       
            types_ytd = (response)         
            dataProvider = generateChartDataYtd();
            chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv_ytd", {
              "type": "pie",
              "theme": "light", 
              "dataProvider": dataProvider,
              "labelText": "[[title]]: [[value]]%",
              "balloonText": "[[title]]: [[value]]% [[[description]]]",
              "titleField": "type",
              "valueField": "percent",
              "descriptionField":"sales",
              "outlineColor": "#FFFFFF",
              "outlineAlpha": 0.8,
              "outlineThickness": 2,
              "colorField": "color",
              "pulledField": "pulled",
              "titles": [{
                "text": ""
              }],
              "listeners": [{
                "event": "clickSlice",
                "method": function(event) {
                  var chart = event.chart;
                  if (event.dataItem.dataContext.id != undefined) {
                    selected = event.dataItem.dataContext.id;
                  } else {
                    selected = undefined;
                  }
                  chart.dataProvider = generateChartDataYtd();
                  chart.validateData();
                }
              }],
              "export": {
                "enabled": true
              }
            });

            AmCharts.addInitHandler(function(chart) {

              // check if data is mepty
              if (chart.dataProvider === undefined || chart.dataProvider.length === 0) {
                // add some dummy data
                var dp = {};
                dp[chart.titleField] = "";
                dp[chart.valueField] = 1;
                chart.dataProvider.push(dp)

                var dp = {};
                dp[chart.titleField] = "";
                dp[chart.valueField] = 1;
                chart.dataProvider.push(dp)

                var dp = {};
                dp[chart.titleField] = "";
                dp[chart.valueField] = 1;
                chart.dataProvider.push(dp)

                // disable slice labels
                chart.labelsEnabled = false;

                // add label to let users know the chart is empty
                chart.addLabel("50%", "50%", "The chart contains no data for selected month", "middle", 15);

                // dim the whole chart
                chart.alpha = 0.3;
              }

            }, ["pie"]);

                    }, 'json');

Here's the serial chart code: 

jQuery.post('http://...', data, function(response) {
    types_model_ytd = (response)     
    dataProvider = generateChartDataModelYtd(); 

    chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv_model_ytd", {
      "type": "serial",
      "theme": "none",
      "dataProvider": dataProvider,
      "valueAxes": [{
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "position": "left",
        "title": "%"
      }],
      // set startDuration to 0 on older browsers
      "startDuration": supportsSVG() ? 0 : 0,
      "graphs": [{
        "balloonText": "[[category]]: [[value]]% [[[sales]]]",
        "colorField": "color",
        "fillAlphas": 0.9,
        "lineAlpha": 0.2,
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "percent",
        "fixedColumnWidth": 20
      }],
      "chartCursor": {
        "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
        "cursorAlpha": 0,
        "zoomable": false
      },
      "categoryField": "type",
      "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start",
        "labelRotation": 45
      }
    });

    AmCharts.checkEmptyData = function(chart) {
        if (0 == chart.dataProvider.length) {
        // set min/max on the value axis
        chart.valueAxes[0].minimum = 0;
        chart.valueAxes[0].maximum = 0;

        // add dummy data point
        var dataPoint = {
          dummyValue: 0
        };
        dataPoint[chart.categoryField] = '';
        chart.dataProvider = [dataPoint];

        // set opacity of the chart div
        chart.chartDiv.style.opacity = 0.5;

        //remove balloonText and labels
        chart.categoryAxis.labelFunction = function(valueText) {
          return '';
        }
        // add label
        chart.addLabel(1, '50%', 'The chart contains no data for selected month', 'center');

        // redraw it
        chart.validateNow();
      }
    }
      AmCharts.checkEmptyData(chart); 

            }, 'json');
```

I have tried every solution I could find but nothing works, any help or suggestions will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you setting an empty array to start the chart? `dataProvider: []` should do it.

Comment: I have tried your solution by converting the dataProvider from object to array but the charts are still showing blank.

Comment: The other working charts are using dataProvider as an object. I don't know what I'm missing here

Comment: You really need arrays for the [dataProvider](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#dataProvider). Also make sure the chart doesn't start with `dataProvider` undefined.

Comment: I have tried your suggestions but it still doesn't work and also making sure dataProvider isn't undefined.

Comment: I have the same issue regarding adding the no data label